# Stop mongodump from overwriting existing files (rename instead)

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

From mongodocs:

**Overwrite Files**

"Mongodump overwrites output files if they exist in the backup data folder. Before running the mongodump command multiple times, either ensure that you no longer need the files in the output folder (the default is the dump/ folder) or rename the folders or files."

Hey guys,
I want to do a daily backup and sometimes even two backups a day. The Dump-filename gets named by the actual date. If I backup twice a day, the first backup gets overwritten due to same names.
Is there any way to tell mongodump to rename (in e.g. 5.9.2016(1)) the file if it already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [--out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--out) option of mongodump to specify the path where to dummp the data.

Create a script that run mongodump and give different name for your path, i.e. using a date:

```
mongodump --out /data/dump/090516/
```

Shell script example:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=$DIR
mkdir $DEST
mongodump --out=/data/dump/$DEST
```

Comment: Nice suggestion but I'm already using the date to change the name. The problem appears if you have more than one backup a day e.g. if someone wants to restore data and needs an extra backup for the data of this day.

Thats why I need an option where mongodump just renames the file (with a (1) or sth) instead of overwriting...

Comment: you can do that using the script. just create a counter, increment it and add it in the name, along the date or not.